# xampp wordpress virtual hosts - css errors, css not being applied

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, apache

I am completely new to php and WordPress.

I tried to setup VirtualHosts since I'm working on multiple wp sites, but after doing so my sites aren't showing any CSS, I can't figure out how to navigate to the admin panel anymore and just general errors.

sshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPjwM.jpg, https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8Hih.jpg

My guess is something to do with paths is screwed up, but I have no idea what to change.

Here is my httpd.vhosts:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ##ServerName or ##ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wp.market-test.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/wp-vs-481"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/wp-vs-481">
        Options Includes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help would be great

Edit: Removed outdated directives, issue persists.

Comment: It looks like your vhost looks good. Could you check does your script is binding to an ip address?

Comment: Sorry for any ignorance, brand new to this stack.

I have changed my drivers/etc/hosts file to reflect my virtualhost, if by chance that's what you're asking

Comment: Can you provide us with apache version? ***"The Allow, Deny, and Order directives, provided by mod_access_compat, are deprecated. You should avoid using them, and avoid outdated tutorials recommending their use."***

Comment: I believe it is version 2.4

Comment: Can you check it with `apache2 -v` ***OUTPUT*** like `Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 27 2017 15:20:24
`  Because `Order deny,allow ` is deprecated, new syntax is 'Require host 1.2.3.4` `Require not host 10.0.1.11` `Require ip ip-address` `Require not host gov` you tweak this to your policy.  NOTE: A simple update may upgrade from 2.4.1 to latest which will render old syntax useless

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the siteurl/home page in the phpadmin config. My problems were mostly caused by using a outdated guide. Make sure to use a recent guide!

Answer (score 0):

### Order, allow,deny not working?

*Let's fix it*

**Possible Cause:**

- Using deprecated syntax
- Moved content to new server

  ***"The Allow, Deny, and Order directives, provided by mod_access_compat, are deprecated. You should avoid using them, and avoid outdated tutorials recommending their use."***

**STEP 1**

Check your apache web server version with `apache2 -v`

***OUTPUT***  should look similar to:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 27 2017 15:20:24
```

**STEP 2**

Because `Order deny,allow` are deprecated, updated syntax as of this date are as follows:

```
Require host 1.2.3.4 
Require not host 10.0.1.11 
Require ip ip-address 
Require not host gov
```

You can create **Access Control** to fit security policy as deemed necessary.

**It' was working just after an update it stopped?**
NOTE: A simple update may upgrade from 2.4.x to latest which will render old syntax useless

To learn more about this, visit [Apache Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/access.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please check once by changing the "**home**" and "**siteurl**" at **wp_option** table. Hope it will work if you change it to **wp.market-test.com** from **127.0.0.1/wp-vs-481**